# Is T4MVC compatible with Portable Actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

T4MVC works nice with traditional ASP.NET MVC structure. But will it work with Portable Areas (feature from MvcContrib)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do portable areas contain all the files that would normally be in the app (controllers and Views)? If so, I would expect T4MVC to work.

If you are running into a specific issue, please update your question with more info.

Comment: So I will need a separate T4MVC templace for each project with Portable Areas? And what if I need to refernce Action from another Portable Area?

Comment: This wouldn't work well. I guess to make it fully work, the template would need to be modified to harvest information fro all the relevant areas at once, but this would likely be a non-trivial change.

Comment: However, I have a separate project containg the Admin portable area and T4MVC does not pick up the folders and files under the Admin folder. Only Admin folder exists at the root of my project and inside this folder there are Controllers, Views, etc. The structure is as described in Portable Areas examples.